# Solve Microsoft.Crm.CrmArgumentNullException: callManagerInfo in plugins and webservices?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am using Crm dynamics 365 .

The system was working perfectly i did not change any library but after some business logic changes I always get an error

> Microsoft.Crm.CrmArgumentNullException: callManagerInfo

in plugins and in web services whenever I am trying update anything from code to crm

An example from plugin error :

> Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: OrganizationServiceFault, our plugin threw exception: callManagerInfoDetail:
>       
>         2b16c280-3ba9-4f53-b6b4-a3dd6f784582
>         -2147220891
>         
>           
>             OperationStatus
>             0
>           
>           
>             SubErrorCode
>             -2146233088
>           
>         
>         OrganizationServiceFault, our plugin threw exception: callManagerInfo
>         2019-10-22T06:48:41.9265174Z
>         false

```
[k.3.CRM.Plugins: k._3.CRM.Plugins.Contact.Contact]
[d0f3ba28-9fb5-e811-a2b9-005056bb6128: k._3.CRM.Plugins.Contact.Contact: Create of contact]

Entered k._3.CRM.Plugins.Contact.Contact.Execute(), Correlation Id: 75bbec96-cbda-4c0d-a449-a2a8a83be135, Initiating User: aa60b85b-9603-e911-a2b5-005056bba55e
k._3.CRM.Plugins.Contact.Contact is firing for Entity: contact, Message: Create, Correlation Id: 75bbec96-cbda-4c0d-a449-a2a8a83be135, Initiating User: aa60b85b-9603-e911-a2b5-005056bba55e
   CREATE: Execution Depth 1
   CREATE: SetS4YlId
   CREATE: SetCountry
Lookup was changed
Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]: callManagerInfo (Fault Detail is equal to Exception details: 
ErrorCode: 0x80040203
Message: callManagerInfo
TimeStamp: 2019-10-22T06:48:41.9116966Z
OriginalException: Microsoft.Crm.CrmArgumentNullException: callManagerInfo ---&gt; System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: callManagerInfo
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxCallManager.CheckCallTracker(SandboxCallInfo sandboxCallInfo)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxSdkListener.AuthenticateCaller(SandboxCallInfo callInfo, SandboxSdkContext requestContext, String operation)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxSdkListener.Execute(SandboxCallInfo callInfo, SandboxSdkContext requestContext, String operation, Byte[] serializedRequest)
ExceptionSource: SdkClient
--
Exception details: 
ErrorCode: 0x80040216
Message: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: callManagerInfo
TimeStamp: 2019-10-22T06:48:41.9116966Z
--
)., Correlation Id: 75bbec96-cbda-4c0d-a449-a2a8a83be135, Initiating User: aa60b85b-9603-e911-a2b5-005056bba55e
Exiting k._3.CRM.Plugins.Contact.Contact.Execute(), Correlation Id: 75bbec96-cbda-4c0d-a449-a2a8a83be135, Initiating User: aa60b85b-9603-e911-a2b5-005056bba55e


</TraceText>
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

and example from web services error :

```
callManagerInfo Server stack trace: 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message) Exception rethrown at [0]: 
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) 
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) 
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService.Update(Entity entity) 
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.UpdateCore(Entity entity) 
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.Update(Entity entity) 
at k._0.XRM_MIDDLELAYER_COMMON.CRMRepo.Repos.GenericCRMRepo.Update(Entity entity) in D:\Source\Schrack\00_MSCRM_and_INTEGRATION\k.0.XRM_MIDDLELAYER_COMMON\CRMRepo\Repos\GenericCRMRepo.cs:line 171 
at k._0.XRM_MIDDLELAYER_COMMON.CRMRepo.Repos.SchrackCRMRepo.Update(Entity entity) in D:\Source\Schrack\00_MSCRM_and_INTEGRATION\k.0.XRM_MIDDLELAYER_COMMON\CRMRepo\Repos\SchrackCRMRepo.cs:line 223 
at k._1.XRM_MIDDLELAYER_ASYNC.Repositories.Incoming.Actions.IncomingDebitAction.Execute()
```

I searched a lot online found many suggestion like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42764033/crm-365-callmanagerinfo-error-in-plugins) or in others who suggest that is because of change of version like [here](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/309073/qualifying-a-lead-and-getting-an-error-e/895090) but actually I did not change the version and I tried the fix but it does not help me.

Any suggestions how I could get over this error?

Comment: The error is **"Value cannot be null."**  Look about two thirds of the way down the plugin error text, at the line that starts with "OriginalException".

Comment: yes but after debug the value is not null

Comment: I don't know what that means.  Find out why the value is null at the time the error occurred, and you will be on the way to solving your problem.

Comment: this problem occuring what ever we change an old entity updating like if we update some feld value creating new entitys......
we are pretty sure that not thing is null

Comment: Then you have to answer the question "Why does this think the value is null when we don't think it is?"

Comment: In other words, you might have to do some *actual debugging.*

Comment: thanks for advice but as I TOLD above i get this error in debugging when ever we try to update or create  any entity in crm i was debugging for the last two day !!!

Comment: The error is most likely a result of the business logic changes you described. I'm guessing that a mandatory field is no longer mandatory on a CRM form, but the plugin code assumes that the field always has a value. What business logic changes have you made? Without seeing the code your plugin is using, there's not much else that we can suggest